# How can I remove all spaces in the beginning of the string?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// posts
+----+--------------+
| id |  subject     |
+----+--------------+
| 1  |    subject 1 |
| 2  | subject 2    |
| 3  |   subject 3  |
| 4  |  subject 4   |
| 5  | subject 5    |
+----+--------------+
```

I need to remove all spaces that are in the beginning of the `subject` column. Here is my current code:

```
UPDATE posts set subject = REPLACE(subject, ' ', '') WHERE 1;
```

And here is **the current result:**

```
+----+--------------+
| 1  | subject1     |
| 2  | subject2     |
| 3  | subject3     |
| 4  | subject4     |
| 5  | subject5     |
+----+--------------+
```

And here is **the expected result:**

```
+----+--------------+
| 1  | subject 1    |
| 2  | subject 2    |
| 3  | subject 3    |
| 4  | subject 4    |
| 5  | subject 5    |
+----+--------------+
```

See? Just the spaces that are in the beginning of the string should be removed. Noted that there is a thing in regex (I tested in PHP) `^` which is exactly what I'm looking for. But I don't know how should I use it in MySQL. Any idea?

Comment: Hint:  `TRIM()`.

Comment: if all rows contain  only subject you can try  REPLACE(subject, 't', 't ')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `trim ()` function

Update posts

`set subject=trim(subject) where 1`

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql> select ltrim('      abc');
+--------------------+
| ltrim('      abc') |
+--------------------+
| abc                |
+--------------------+
```